# ¿El problema de Hackerrank, normalizacion de base de datos N#9, no tiene una respuesta correcta?

Tags: base-de-datos

Tengo una duda con el ejercicio N#9 de normalización de base de datos en Hackerrank, creo que en este ejercicio, no existe ninguna respuesta correcta.

Enlace al ejercicio https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/database-normalization-9/problem

El enunciado del ejercicio es el siguiente, lo traduciré al español.

> Considerando la siguiente relacion y sus determinantes, las llaves están en negrita.
> R(**a**,**b**,c,d,e)
> ¿Cuál de los siguientes determinantes NO es una llave candidata?
>
> 1. a,c -> b,d,e
> 2. a,d -> b
> 3. a,c,e -> b,d

Ahora, ¿Por que creo yo que no tiene una respuesta correcta?, es por lo siguiente.

1. En a,c -> b,d,e, su determinante(a,c) es una llave candidata, por que su cierre de atributos tiene todos los atributos de la relacion, en otras palabras, puede ser una llave primaria, así que esta esta descartada
2. En a,d -> b, su determinante(a,d) es una llave candidata, ya que si "b" es parte de la llave primaria y por los axiomas de Armstrong, la regla de reflexividad, donde, Si α es un conjunto de
   atributos y β ⊆ α, entonces se cumple que α → β, si esto es así, entonces, a,d -> a, y por la regla de la unión, si a,d -> a y a,d -> b, entonces, a,d -> a,b, y como a,b es una llave primaria (a,b -> c,d,e), entonces, a,d es una llave candidata.
3. En a,c,e -> b,d, su determinante(a,c,e) es una llave candidata, ya que su cierre de atributos tiene todos los atributos de la relacion.

Entonces, si todos los determinantes son llaves candidatas, ¿Cuál es la respuesta correcta?, o, ¿Mi método es erróneo?

Comment: No estoy familiarizado con esos axiomas, pero respecto a #2 si α = {a,b} y β = {a,d}, entonces β  no es un subconjunto de α (ya que d no pertenece a α). Intuitivamente(repito, no estoy familiarizado con esta teoría) diría que es una clave candidata, si con {a,d} puedes determinar b entonces para cada {a,d} tienes un {a,b} (a viene dado, b se obtiene por la relación) que sí es una clave, pero el razonamiento parece incorrecto.

Comment: Otro punto a considerar es que si #1 es correcto, #3 no lo puede ser *al mismo tiempo* ya que e depende de {a, c} y entonces {a, c, e} no es irreductible. Pero el enunciado no parece indicar que tengamos que considerar las distintas combinaciones (no tenemos que asumir que #1 es cierta para evaluar #3 ni al revés).

Comment: @SJuan76, tienes razón de que el razonamiento es incorrecto, entonces, ¿Qué tal si nos basamos también en la regla de la unión de los axiomas de Amstrong para tener un buen razonamiento?, si por la regla de reflexión, a,d -> a, entonces, por la regla de la unión, si a,d -> a y a,d -> b, entonces, a,d -> a,b, y como a,b es una clave primaria, entonces, a,d es una llave candidata, ¿No?.

Comment: Esa vendría a ser una formalización de mi intuición, sí. Hasta donde puedo ver, #2 es una clave candidata, y tampoco veo problemas con las otras. Puede ser un error en la pregunta, o que quiso poner una pregunta trampa (mira lo comentario anterior) y no lo expresó bien.

Comment: Si, el mismo autor ha realizado todos los problemas de normalización de base de datos en Hackerrank, y el problema N#5 y el N#6, también tienen respuestas erróneas, me parece increíble, ya que Hackerrank me parece una pagina bastante famosa, bueno, editare la pregunta corrigiendo el razonamiento, gracias @SJuan76 :D.

Comment: @SJuan76, Aun despues de darle vuelta a tu segundo comentario sobre la pregunta trampa, aun no entiendo, ¿Con que te refieres sobre "e depende de {a,c} y entonces {a,c,e} no es irreductible"?

Comment: Los atributos de una clave deben ser independientes entre sí, si (a,c)->e entonces e no es parte de la clave (creo que la propiedad se llama irreducibilidad). Por eso, 1. es incompatible con 3. Pero si la idea fuera una trampa de ese tipo, estaría muy mal expresada.